# My Graphics wont Show Up when I export my Java Project

Tags: java, eclipse, image, export

Im working on a Java Project and it contains images. However, when I export my Java project as a Runnable Jar File or just a Jar File, none of the images appear on the screen. It works fine in the IDE im using(Eclipse).

I already tried all of the many methods people have posted. I made my res folder a main folder as well.

```
    newFrame.setTitle("Mustache Clicker");
     jLabel1.setText(i + "");
     URL mustache1 = mainscreen.class.getResource("/images/mustache.png");
     ImageIcon mustache = new ImageIcon(mustache1);
     URL mustache2 = mainscreen.class.getResource("/images/Mustache Mine.png");
     ImageIcon miner = new ImageIcon(mustache2);
     URL mustache3 = mainscreen.class.getResource("/images/Auto .png");
     ImageIcon auto = new ImageIcon(mustache3);
     URL mustache4 = mainscreen.class.getResource("/images/mustache (1).png");
     ImageIcon rain = new ImageIcon(mustache4);
     URL mustache5 = mainscreen.class.getResource("/images/city.png");
     ImageIcon city = new ImageIcon(mustache5);
     jButton2.setIcon(miner);
     jButton1.setIcon(mustache);
     jButton3.setIcon(auto);
     jButton4.setIcon(rain);
     jButton5.setIcon(city);
```

Comment: First thing to do is verify that the images are indeed packed into the jar file and at what path exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do "images/Auto.png". I'm guessing it because it is a file pathing issue.
Maybe even possibly "../images/Auto.png"

Comment: I just tried it, it didn't work for me. However, thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Is it throwing any exceptions? Also can you tell me your project hierarchy?

Comment: No there are no current exceptions. Il put up the project hiearchy.

Comment: If you run your application from a command line it will show you the exceptions, just in case you did not know.

Comment: Thanks I didn't know that, you learn something new everyday. Anyways here is the image: https://imgur.com/a/UHohrpL

Comment: Try putting it into a resource folder. so resource -> images.

Comment: Also, run your application from cmd. Do java -jar YourApp.jar and see what exceptions you get if any.

Comment: Thank you! Il try that.

Comment: It appears I get an error when I assign the image to the ImageIcon. For example, right here I get an error,  ImageIcon mustache = new ImageIcon(mustache1);

Comment: Yeah that means its not finding the file. Create a new resource folder and put images folder in that then try.

Comment: I opened up the jar file and I saw that it does contain my image folder. Now im wondering why it wont get the files.

Comment: Are you going to File->Export->Runnable Jar file-> etc? Also, right click on your project, add new, Source Folder, name it resources, and add your images file to that.

Comment: I am, I tried making the src folder again like you said. It didn't work. Can i Send you a video of what is happening?

Comment: Image img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("resources/water.bmp"));
    button.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));

Comment: If that doesn't work, I may ask you zip the project and send it to me through a link.

Comment: Sorry took me long to respond, here is the dropbox link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/trv9zvzii5evsmc/Clicker%20copy%202.zip?dl=0

Comment: Sorry took me a while to respond, thanks for the feedback. Also which snippet are you talking about?